# Codekit: Best practice to not jHint parts of code

Tags: jquery, flexslider, codekit

What the best way to omit a block of code from being checked (by jHint) in Codekit.

The direct example is that I and using FlexSlider which when I paste the provided code from the tutorial page: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/video.html I get a bunch of errors.

I still want the rest of my code to be jHinted just not the stuff that I didn't write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From JSHint's [documentation](http://www.jshint.com/docs/):

> ignore
>
> A directive for telling JSHint to ignore a block of code.

```
// Code here will be linted with JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:start */
// Code here will be linted with ignored by JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

> All code in between ignore:start and ignore:end won't be passed to JSHint so you can use any language extension such as Facebook React. Additionally, you can ignore a single line with a trailing comment:

```
ignoreThis(); // jshint ignore:line
```

Comment: JSHint docs why didn't I check that! I was all over Codekit documentation. Thanks